# Gnome Shell Extension: Send Request with Authorization Bearer Headers

Tags: authentication, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs, libsoup

I am trying to build a gnome shell extension (using gjs) that I need to communicate with an external REST API. In order to do so, I need to accompany my requests with the header: `Authorization: Bearer <token>` and with a `Content-Type: application/json`.

I have looked all over for questions like this and I did find some similar ones but none of them works. The documentation is not helpful at all, and, if anything, it has only confused me more.

With curl I could send that request as follows:

```sh
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" <url>
```

So far, I have only created extensions that send simple GET requests with no headers. Then I would do the following:

```js
const Soup = imports.gi.Soup;
let soupSyncSession = new Soup.SessionSync();

let message = Soup.Message.new('GET', url);
let responseCode = soupSyncSession.send_message(message);
let res;
if(responseCode == 200) {
    res = JSON.parse(message['response-body'].data);
}
```

Any idea on how I can add the headers? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.request_headers` is a [`Soup.MessageHeaders`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/soup24%7E2.72.0/soup.messageheaders) object to which you can [`append()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/soup24%7E2.72.0/soup.messageheaders#method-append) the authorization and content type headers.

Additionally there is a convenient [`set_content_type()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/soup24%7E2.72.0/soup.messageheaders#method-set_content_type) method for the content type header specifically.

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT:

By using @ptomato's answer I ended up using the following code:

```js
function send_request(url, type='GET') {
    let message = Soup.Message.new(type, url);
    message.request_headers.append(
        'Authorization',
        `Bearer ${token}`
    )
    message.request_headers.set_content_type("application/json", null);
    let responseCode = soupSyncSession.send_message(message);
    let out;
    if(responseCode == 200) {
        try {
            out = JSON.parse(message['response-body'].data);
        } catch(error) {
            log(error);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

## Initial Comment:

So, I managed to find a workaround but it is not efficient and so I will not mark it as the accepted answer. If anyone knows how to answer my question using `Soup`, please answer!

My workaround involves using the `imports.misc.util` file which includes the function `spawnCommandLine` for executing shell commands. So, I used `curl` in order to download the json to a file (the `path` variable below):

```js
Util.spawnCommandLine(`/usr/bin/curl -X ${type} -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" ${url} -o ${path}`);
```

and then I read the contents by using the following:

```js
let text = GLib.file_get_contents(path)[1];
let json_result = JSON.parse(text);
```

This is not efficient at all and there should be an easier way around. But, until that is found, I hope this will be able to help someone else.